# Null values are creating error in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

So i am importing the Excel sheet into datagridview. But unfortunately some empty tuples are included inside. The image will be of some help. The extra NULL tuples are 41 and 42. Now when i am calculating the percentage from the data of these tuples with a loop, the loop hits these empty rows and shows the

```
 Error:{"Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid."}
```

[image].

What to do..Any suggestions will be of great help!Thank you...

Comment: Show us your code so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert an If condition to first evaluate if the cell contents are dbnull. Here is an example where I use it in some of my own projects:

```
If IsDBNull(part.Item("Assignment Category")) = False Then
      newOracleHREmployeeRecord.AssignmentCategory = CStr(part.Item("Assignment Category"))
End If
```